# Return values to custom framework in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, xcode6

I have created one custom static framework by following http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios tutorial.

**Edit** : Can we call database file inside the framework? My DB file contains formulas which calculate input values and return the output.

How to achieve this task. Any sample code would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're able to create a static library you should be able to call a function or method in that library, right? What are you missing? Describe your actual problem and we can help you.

Comment: Ok. finally I got it. It was easy but doing it first time so took time for me to understand. Error: Method was not properly declared.

Comment: One more query, Can we call database file inside the framework? DB file having formulas which calculate values and return the output...